# Laravel 4 timstamp

Tags: laravel-4

I have a field in mysql table with type 'TIMESTAMP' and using a calendar on my view to get date in format dd/MM/YYYY. Inserting data with following code

```
$billing = new Billing;
$billing->date = Input::get('date');
$billing->save();
```

It is filling data with 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in my field. How can i get correct value. I also tried to convert it to timestamp as followed.

```
$billing = new Billing;
$billing->date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime(Input::get('date')));
$billing->save();
```

But it is also not working...Can any one help!!!

Answer (score 1):

if I understand you correctly, mysql timestamps have to be saved as strings in YYYY-mm-dd HH:ii:ss format (ie, as returned by date('Y-m-d H:i:s')).  You could convert with `date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), strtotime(Input::get('date')))`